# Integration of improper integrals

Tags: calculus

Consider:

$$\int \frac{4}{7e^{-2x}+1}dx$$

$$u=-2x$$ $$du=-2$$

$$4{\frac{-1}{2}}\int \frac{-2}{7e^{u}+1}dx$$

$$= -2ln|7e^{-2x}+1|+C$$

But doesn't the integral have to be of the form

$$\int{u^{-1}du}$$

to do that??

$$4\int{\frac{1}{(\sqrt[2]{(7e^{-x})^2+1^2})^2dx}}$$

$$a=1$$ $$u=7e^{-x}$$

$$x=?$$

Would this be the correct way to do it or is the first way correct?

Comment: $$\int \frac{-2}{7e^{u} + 1} du \ne -2\ln \lvert 7e^{u} + 1 \rvert + C$$

Comment: @Mattos ok what is the correct way to solve?

Comment: Some answer is good enough. Another note: What you are doing is finding **primitives**.

Comment: This might be called an improper primitive (but maybe saying "wrong primitive" is better).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither of your answers are correct unfortunately.  It would actually be easier to write $\frac{4}{7e^{-2x} + 1} = \frac{4e^{2x}}{7 + e^{2x}}$.  Take $u = e^{2x}, \; du = 2e^{2x}dx$.  We therefore get

$$
\int \frac{4e^{2x}}{7+e^{2x}} dx \;\; =\;\; \int \frac{2}{7+u} du \;\; =\;\; 2\ln(7+u) + c \;\; =\;\; 2\ln(7+e^{2x})+c.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Let us make the problem more general considering $$I=\int \frac{A}{B+C e^{D x}}dx$$ and change variable $B+C e^{D x}=u$, that is to say $x=\frac 1D{\log \left(\frac{u-B}{C}\right)}$ and $dx=\frac{1}{D (u-B)}$. Replacing, we arrive to $$I=\frac{A}D\int\frac{du}{ u (u-B)}=\frac{A}{BD}\Big(\int\frac{du}{ u-B}-\int\frac{du}{ u} \Big)=\frac{A}{BD}\log\Big(\frac{ u-B}u\Big)+K$$ Back to $x$, then $$I=\frac AB\Big(x-\frac{1}{D}\log \left(B+C e^{D x}\right)\Big)+K$$